# How can I add css to a word inside a div that matches the word from the search box?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a searchbox where you can search for words and pages will display with the searched-for word in the description of the page(meaning if the word you searched for is in the description of the page then it will display a link to the page and the description of the page). I need to be able to take the word searched-for and from the description that is displayed in the result, I need that word highlighted in the description. 
Here is what I have so far. But this is not working.

```
var searchValue = $(".search-query").val(); //searchValue is the word you type in the input box

$( ".searchResults-description:contains('" + searchValue + "')").css("background-color", "#fadcd9" );
```

please help! When I click search the word stays in my searchbox. I slapped it back in the input box after page reload. but not I need this word to be highlighted in the description div, whereever this word shows up in it.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? I've tested your code in this context and it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/qht2xy4g/

Comment: tl;dr The OP what's the search box to acts as a filtering CMD/CTR + F for the descriptions. Highlighting ONLY the actual word in the description.

Comment: OP, please add some html so we know the format of the descriptions

Answer (score -1):

You're checking for the value of the search box on page load, so the `searchValue` variable is always going to be empty. What you need to do is get the value when the input changes. One way you can do this is with a [keyup function](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/). This should get you started:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.search-query').keyup(function() {
    var searchValue = $(".search-query").val();
    $( ".searchResults-description:contains('" + searchValue + "')").css("background-color", "#fadcd9" );
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="search-query" />

<div class="searchResults-description">Lorem</div>
<div class="searchResults-description">Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: i mean... we don't really know that... it may have just been left out of the question. We don't even know what "not working" means in this case.

Comment: it doesn't even work

Comment: [Yes it does](https://imggmi.com/full/2019/3/1/bbd23a443e700391c1b1cf96d2dc7235-full.png.html).

Comment: Type "L", then press backspace.

Comment: "This should get you started." I was simply explaining why the code OP provided was not working. I'm not going to assume to know the exact functionality they're looking for.